# VB.NET How can I check if a PictureBox contains an image?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using VB.NET forms app and I need to check if a PictureBox currently has an image in it. How would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
If Not pictureBox.Image is Nothing Then
    //do stuff here
Else
    //do other stuff
End If
```